# Why Am I Getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null"

Tags: javascript

I am creating a popup to let the user share. The code is:

```
var ShareContent = document.getElementById("Share-Content");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var ShareButton = document.getElementById("ShareBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var ShareSpan = document.getElementsByClassName("close Share")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
ShareButton.onclick = function() {
  ShareContent.style.display = "block";
};

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
ShareSpan.onclick = function() {
  ShareContent.style.display = "none";
};

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == ShareContent) {
    ShareContent.style.display = "none";
  }
};
```

HTML Code:

```
<!-- Button -->
<button class="DefaultButton" id="ShareBtn">
   Share
</button>
<!-- Share Popup -->
    <div class="Share">
      <div class="Share-Content">
        <span class="close Share">Close &times;</span>
        <p>
          Share:
        </p>
        <div class="flex-container"> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

But when I run it, I get:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`.
If it helps, I have another popup with this code.

```
var modal = document.getElementById("Popup");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("PopupButton");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close Settings")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
};

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
};

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
};
```

It runs like this:

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("Popup");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("PopupButton");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close Settings")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
};

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
};

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
};
```

```css
.Popup {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}
.Popup-Content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 30px;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
}@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.close:hover {
  color: black;
```

```html
<html>
   <button class="DefaultButton PopupButton" id="PopupButton">
    Settings
   </button>
    <div id="Popup" class="Popup">
      <div class="Popup-Content">
        <span class="close Settings">Close &times;</span>
        <p>
          Settings:
        </p>
        <button
        >
          Dark Mode
        </button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I know the code error is because of the "modal" variable, but I have no idea how to resolve it. If anyone can help, I would greatly appreciate it.
The error is coming from

```
ShareButton.onclick = function() {
  ShareContent.style.display = "block";
};
```

Specifically from:
`.style.display = "block";`

Comment: the [`.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById#return_value) returns `null` if there is no element with the given `id` - there is no element with `id` that equals `Share-Content` _at the time that statement is executed_

Comment: In the HTML there is a button with the id `Share-Content`.

Comment: @theknightD2 can you attach `.html` code to your question?

Comment: `In the HTML there is a button with the id Share-Content` yes but if that script appears in your page before the HTML does, then it will be executed immediately, and _at that moment_ the browser won't have parsed the HTML containing the `Share-Content` element yet, and therefore it won't exist in the DOM, and therefore JavaScript can't find it. It's not clear how it all fits together in your real page, but the order that items appear in your page can be important (unless you do things like wrap the script in a DomContentLoaded event handler, for example).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event

Comment: If you wrap your current code inside of a handler attached to that event, more than likely you'll get around the error you are encountering now. As people above are pointing out, your code is executing before the dom finishes rendering.

Comment: @ADyson: The code is executed at the end of the `<body>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, there are two main reasons that may cause this error:

1. You need to make sure that you are not setting a property for a non-existing element - maybe you did not write the identifier correctly-
2. Probably because the element is called before the DOM is ready. Always make sure that you are accessing a DOM element when it is ready, placing the JS file at the top of the HTML page causes such errors too! Make sure that you are placing the js file path at the end of the body and inside the body.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as mentioned in previous comments, I have already addressed this problem, and yes, the JS file is at the bottom of the `<head>`.

Comment: If it is at the bottom of the <head> this might be the reason why you get the error! 
try to move it down at the bottom of the <body> as I mentioned not the <head>. I had the same issue a couple of weeks ago and that was what caused the error for me.
Wish you good luck.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the bottom of the `<body>`. (I always get those two confused...)

Answer (score 2):

These are the following mistakes that you have made in your code:

1. You have not accessed your ShareSpan close.Share div correctly you must try `.close.Share` as your selector using below code.

   var ShareSpan = document.querySelector("close.Share");

This was giving you your first error  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`

2. You have your  `<div class="Share-Content">` with a class of `Share-Content` but you are trying to access it using `document.getElementById("Share-Content")`, that's why you get the error.

   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

when you try to do  `ShareContent.style.display = "none";` in your Javascript.

In the below Code snippet I have tackled both the Errors:

**CODE WITHOUT ERRORS:** ( I leave the implementation to you because I feel you better know your code specifications) :)

```js
var ShareContent = document.querySelector(".Share-Content"); // Correction here

// Get the button that opens the modal
var ShareButton = document.getElementById("ShareBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var ShareSpan = document.querySelector(".close.Share"); // Correction Here

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
ShareButton.onclick = function() {
  ShareContent.style.display = "block";
};

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
ShareSpan.onclick = function() {
  ShareContent.style.display = "none";
};

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == ShareContent) {
    ShareContent.style.display = "none";
  }
};
```

```html
<!-- Button -->
<button class="DefaultButton" id="ShareBtn">
   Share
</button>
<!-- Share Popup -->
    <div class="Share">
      <div class="Share-Content">
        <span class="close Share">Close &times;</span>
        <p>
          Share:
        </p>
        <div class="flex-container"> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: My code now has the error ` Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of undefined`. The error is here:

Comment: `ShareSpan.onclick = function() {`

Comment: Under the `= function() {`

Comment: Yes, You are right :) The error is happening because your ShareContent variable is null. Because you have used ShareContent.style.display = "none"; but ShareContent was wrongly accessed with document.getElementById().. Let me update my Answer... There actually are two errors:) Please check my code in a moment :)

Comment: Unfortunately no. The code not working I highly suspect is due to the other modal. It seems that the other modal slightly malfunctions whenever the share modal has an error.   The popup doesn't show up when the button is pressed. Sorry about this trouble :(

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all so much for your answers. But I have solved this problem. It turns out I was missing a `<id>` tag in the button, causing the js script to search for an id that was nonexistent. But thank you for your help.